Move file to failed in camel route
A camel route is used to handle multi-row csv files. The route from is configured with the query parameter moveFailed. This all basically works. But the rows are processed one by one and in case of error, it route shall not stop but shall continue. Afterwards, the file should be moved to failed if any error has occurred.
Question: How to trigger "move to fail" in the code?
The code looks basically like this:
        from("file:/C:/dev/_import?moveFailed=failed&delete=true&readLock=changed")
        .onException(Throwable.class)
            .setHeader("fileFailedPartly").simple("true")
            .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "${exception.stacktrace}")
            .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "Exception occurred when reading row - continue with file ${header.CamelFileName}")
            .continued(true)
        .end()
        .bean(CsvParser.class)
        .split().body()
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Sending row ${header.CamelSplitIndex}++ of ${header.CamelSplitSize}")
            .delay(1000)
            .bean("sender","send")
        .end()
        .choice()
            .when(simple("${header.fileFailedPartly} == true"))
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "File ${header.CamelFileName} partly failed. Move to failed.")
                
                //trigger move to failed
        .end();

I may should add that the application is quarkus based, thus quarkus-camel is used.

That should be the default behaviour. It will process every line separately as a single message after the split().body() and if you get at least one error, the file is being moved to the failed directory. If it was succesfully processed, it will be deleted (because of delete=true).
You don't need the exception handler for this scenario at all. The following lines should be enough:
from("file:/C:/dev/_import?moveFailed=failed&delete=true&readLock=changed")
        .bean(CsvParser.class)
        .split().body()
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Sending row ${header.CamelSplitIndex}++ of ${header.CamelSplitSize}")
            .delay(1000)
            .bean("sender","send")
        .end();

If there is an error, the current line will fail, will produce an exception with stacktrace and everything, but the route will neither crash nor stop, but continue with the next line.
